# PayPal - patch order amount higher than approved

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Apologies for what is probably a silly question but I'm struggling to find the solution in the PayPal documentation.

Scenario - customer has an item in their basket, say value of it is £5.00.

My current workflow is I display the PayPal button, user clicks on it and I create an order valued at £5 and on approval drop down to a screen showing their delivery address and our shipping options (which may range from simple post to full delivery and installation).

When asking for approval from the customer the small print suggests to the customer that we may take £7.00 to account for tax and shipping.

[image: Screenshot of PayPal asking customer for approval]

But say the £5 item is bulky and to ship it costs another £4 bringing the total to £9.00?

Server side I patch the order to make the new amount £9 and breakdown the amount between subtotal and shipping but on capture (server side) I get an error from PayPal saying that the user needs to approve the amount but with no hints, either in the returned JSON or in PayPal documentation on how I should deal with this.

I could potentially add my shipping options as a drop down to the approval stage but unfortunately some of our shipping options have detailed T&Cs (such as you must be at home, delivery restrictions etc.) that can't be added to the PayPal popup.

What is best-practice to deal with this? I don't really want to take the customer back around the loop again. Just a link to the documentation which has very little detail.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** - return JSON from the attempted capture of an amount over approved amount

```
    {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
     "details":[{"issue":"PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED",
     "description":"Payer needs to perform the following action before 
                    proceeding with payment."}],
      "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically 
                 incorrect, or failed business 
                 validation.","debug_id":"4dd58ca1b18d","links":[{"href":
"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED",
"rel":"information_link",
"method":"GET"}]}
```

Comment: Show the returned JSON

Comment: Done - please see edit

Answer (score 1):

Hard to comment without seeing a log of what you're doing and the response, but here are a pair of sample requests that worked in sandbox testing:

Simple order creation:

```json
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "value": "77.44",
        "currency_code": "USD"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After creation, it was approved by a sandbox payer.

Then patched via API with a new amount:

```json
[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
    "value": {
      "currency_code": "USD",
      "value": "155.33"
    }
  }
]
```

And finally captured as usual, with normal success.

Comment: See the JSON I'm getting above. I'm doing a very similar Patch that gets accepted with the standard no response.

Comment: Does it happen when patching only the amount, not anything else? Try the simple example above and iterate to isolate the difference vs what you're doing

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was confusing it by adding the extra detail / breakdown.